# List::removeAll с аргументом List::subList работает неправильно

Tags: java, list

Не могу понять, почему при первом варианте удаляет не те элементы, а при работе со вторым вариантом, когда применяю промежуточное копирование, всё работает верно.

```java
public class Seventh {

    private String name;
    
    public Seventh(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Seventh[] sev = {
            new Seventh("1"),
            new Seventh("2"),
            new Seventh("3"),
            new Seventh("4"),
            new Seventh("5") };
        List<Seventh> l = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(l, sev);
        Collections.addAll(l, sev);
        System.out.println(l);
        List<Seventh> sub = l.subList(0, 4);
        System.out.println(sub);
        List<Seventh> copy = new ArrayList<>(l);
        // 1 вариант
        l.removeAll(sub); 
        // 2 вариант
//        copy.removeAll(sub);
//        l = copy;
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Вывод при первом варианте:

[image: Вывод при первом варианте]

Вывод при втором варианте:

[image: Вывод при втором варианте]

Comment: у вас возникает ошибка, хоть она и не отображается, что странно. Ёе можно заметить в дебаге Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.util.ConcurrentModificationException' exception. Она означает, что коллекцию попытались изменить во время итерирования по ней.

Comment: Вы можете создать итератор для данной коллекции и с помощью перебора всех элементов убирать ненужные.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь связана с тем, что метод `subList` создает представление (view) исходного списка `l`, и когда вы изменяете исходный список `l` путем удаления элементов через `l.removeAll(sub)`, это влияет и на подсписок `sub`.

При использовании второго варианта с созданием копии списка `copy` и выполнении операции `copy.removeAll(sub)`, изменения применяются только к копии списка, поэтому вы видите правильный результат.

В этом можно удостовериться, добавив следующий код между строками `System.out.println(sub);` и `List<Seventh> copy = new ArrayList<>(l);`:

```java
System.out.println(sub.get(0));
sub.set(0, new Seventh("qwe"));
System.out.println(sub.get(0));
```

Этот код выведет следующее:

```
1
qwe
```

Таким образом, первый элемент списка `l` и первый элемент списка `sub` ссылаются на один и тот же объект.